# Amplify Salesforce Live Agent chat notifications

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, console, notification, chat

I have been trying to research possibilities on creating my own Salesforce Live Agent (chat) window notifications as the out of the box versions are so inconspicuous they tend to lead to missed chats. The only thing I have really been able to find is idea posts over the last handful of years on the Salesforce forums but none of them have really lead anywhere.

I have used AutoHotKey in the past to do a few things but they were based off of window detection of Windows programs. As the Live Agent seems to be a sub window of your browser (Chrome for me) is it even possible to detect it and then have AHK do "something" to get the user's attention? I have also dabbled with jquery but I am very much a novice with that and am not sure where to even begin.

I figure that seeing there are a multitude of ideas on the Salesforce forums I cannot be the only one to follow this line of thought. Has anyone else been able to get a workaround to Salesforce's Live Agent notifications working to amplify them to make it so the user has no chance of not seeing / hearing them?

Any help / assistance is greatly appreciated even if it is just a direction to go forward with.

Thank you

Comment: I'm in the same boat you're in... you ever find an answer? I'm currently looking at creating utility bar components to at least keep polling and alerting on other SF tabs/windows. I have some users fully in the classic console, and others that also use Lightning, so I'll have to tackle it from both ends.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the new winter 19 feature that could deliver the same output in few line of code. We are routing the live agent via Omni channel.

```
    <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:backgroundUtilityItem" access="global" >
    <aura:handler event="lightning:omniChannelWorkAssigned" action="{! c.onWorkAssigned }" />
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />  
</aura:component>
```

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_console_background_utility_items.htm

Answer (score 1):

We've had about a month of tinkering since rollout to figure out how to keep our team on top of incoming chats (we're using the LiveAgent snap-ins with Omni Channel routing, but this will work for either.

At a minimum, we've found that our users need to have their chat console open in a non-minimized window with no other tabs - or even open in another browser by itself (some use Chrome, but have chat open in Firefox). This prevents suppression of the alert sound from the browser ignoring hidden tabs.

There appear to be some periodically reappearing known issues with the 'status update on push timeout' not working in some orgs. This means that you can't get a user to move to busy/offline when they do miss a chat. This is only really a problem when a single agent is logged in - the visitor chat gets stuck in a waiting state, with no agent to roll over to - and no way for the agent to accept the orphaned chat. So we've recommended that three or more people are logged in at all times.

Additionally, we've created a hidden custom console component for the utility bar that will play a continuous alert sound until the chat is accepted, declined, cancelled, or the agent status has changed. This uses static resources with jquery and an mp3 alert sound (currently the standard LiveAgent sound) - but you could rework it to remove dependence on both. I've removed code for another purpose that needs jquery.

I've also left in a few other commented out events that will be useful in non-Omni Channel implementations.

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="true" docType="html-5.0">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<head>
    <title>ChatAlert</title>
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/40.0/integration.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, '/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')}"/>
</head>

<body>
<audio id="alertsound" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.alertsounds, '/alertsounds/request.mp3')}" autostart="false"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    var init = function () {
        sforce.console.chat.onChatCanceled(function (result) {
            console.log('Chat Canceled: ', result);
            endAlertRepeat();
        });

        // sforce.console.chat.onChatRequested(function (result) {
        // });

        // sforce.console.chat.onChatStarted(function (result) {
        // });

        // sforce.console.chat.onChatEnded(function (result) {
        // });

        // sforce.console.chat.onChatDeclined(function (result) {
        // });

        // sforce.console.chat.onChatTransferredOut(function (result) {
        // });

        sforce.console.addEventListener(
            sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.WORK_ASSIGNED,
            function (result) {
                console.log('Work Assigned: ', result);
                startAlertRepeat();
            });

        sforce.console.addEventListener(
            sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.WORK_ACCEPTED,
            function (result) {
                console.log('Work Accepted: ', result);
                endAlertRepeat();
            });

        sforce.console.addEventListener(
            sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.WORK_DECLINED,
            function (result) {
                console.log('Work Declined: ', result);
                endAlertRepeat();
            });

        sforce.console.addEventListener(
            sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.STATUS_CHANGED,
            function (result) {
                console.log('Presence Status changed: ', result);
                endAlertRepeat();
            });

        sforce.console.addEventListener(
            sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.LOGOUT,
            function () {
                console.log('Logged Out');
                endAlertRepeat();
            });

        // sforce.console.addEventListener(
        //     sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.WORK_CLOSED,
        //     function (result) {
        //     });

        // sforce.console.addEventListener(
        //     sforce.console.ConsoleEvent.PRESENCE.WORKLOAD_CHANGED,
        //     function (result) {
        //     });
    },
    alertTimerId = null,
    delayTimerId = null,
    alertCounter = 0,
    playAlertSound = function() {
        var sound = document.getElementById("alertsound");
        sound.play();
    },
    startAlertRepeat = function() {
        if(delayTimerId === null && alertTimerId === null) {
            delayTimerId = window.setTimeout(delayedAlertRepeat, 5500);
        }
    },
    delayedAlertRepeat = function() {
        alertCounter += 1;
        if(alertTimerId === null) {
            alertTimerId = window.setInterval(playAlertSound, 5000);
            delayTimerId = null;
        }
    },
    endAlertRepeat = function() {
        alertCounter = (alertCounter > 0)? alertCounter - 1 : 0;

        if(alertTimerId !== null && alertCounter <= 0) {
            window.clearInterval(alertTimerId);
            alertTimerId = null;
        }

        if(delayTimerId !== null) {
            window.clearTimeout(delayTimerId);
            delayTimerId = null;
        }
    };

    $j(document).ready(function() {
        init();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Hope this helps! We've dropped our missed chats to less than a tenth of what they were on roll out.